# The limit of integer valued random variables must be integer valued?

Tags: probability-theory

I saw something like this:

> If $D_n$ are all integer valued random variables, and $D_n$ converges in distribution to $D$, then $D$ must also be integer valued.

I am a little bit suspicious about the statement. A trivial *"counter example"* might be $D_n \equiv n$ and $D \equiv \infty$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} D_n = D$, $D_n$ converges in distribution to $D$. But can we still say $D$ is integer valued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the distribution of $D_n$, and $P$ the distribution of $D$.
The [portmanteau theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) says that if $P_n\to P$ then 
$$\liminf_n P_n(F)\leq P(F),$$ for any closed set $F\subset \mathbb{R}$. 
Letting $F=\mathbb{Z}$, we see that any limit of integer-valued random variables is integer-valued, since 
$$1=\liminf_n P_n(\mathbb{Z})\leq P(\mathbb{Z}).$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually aware of this theorem and it is how I thought I had proved it. But when I came up with the "counter example" that I got confused again. Can we say that $\infty \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Of course, $\infty$ is not an element in either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. I guess it all depends in which metric space the random variables $D_n,D$ take values. Is it $\mathbb{R}$ or some compactification of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It's not clear whether the author meant to define $D_n$ and $D$ in $\mathbb R$ or compactification of $\mathbb R$. That's a question that comes to me again and again -- When the author says "random variables", does he/she allow them to take $\infty$ as value or not?

Comment: That is up to each author to decide and (hopefully!) clearly state.

Comment: OK. BTW, does my example shows that the portmanteau theorem works only for random variables on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes. The argument fails because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$.